# python: creating chararray of unicode strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, astropy, fits

I need to substitute some data in a `FITS` file that I would like to modify with `astropy.fits` in python3. In order to be consistent with the original FITS file, I would like to write a `numpy.chararray` of `dtype='<U100'`.

I have tried with `numpy.chararray(x)`, where `x` is a list of string, and I get `*** TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

I am very confused because I though that in `python 3` all the string are unicode and in my understanding `'<U100'` is unicode. I would love some hint on what I am doing wrong here

Comment: This is apparently not how you construct a character array. Have a look at the docs for this function (eg. type `help(np.chararray)` in a REPL).

Answer (score 0):

The FITS standard does not deal with unicode. Within astropy.fits when you are writing it will try to encode as ASCII. When you read a FITS file there is some magic under the hood to make the ASCII `bytes` appear like `str`.

The short answer is that you need to use `bytes` if you are trying to deal directly with data stored in FITS.  For instance:

```
In [8]: s = np.array(['hello', 'world'])                                        

In [9]: np.char.encode(s, 'ascii')                                              
Out[9]: array([b'hello', b'world'], dtype='|S5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details of exactly what you're trying to change it's hard to say, but assuming you're working with a FITS table the easiest way is probably to use the Table API.

Here's an example table:

```py
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> t = Table({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
>>> t.write('table.fits')
```

You can load it with `Table.read` and just modify it like any array of strings.  It will handle re-encoding it properly.

```py
>>> t = Table.read('table.fits')
>>> t
<Table length=3>
  a   
bytes1
------
     a
     b
     c
>>> t['a'] = ['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> t.write('table.fits', overwrite=True)
>>> t = Table.read('table.fits')
>>> t
<Table length=3>
  a   
bytes1
------
     d
     e
     f
```

If you want to use the lower-level FITS interface directly that's fine too.  In most cases it shouldn't be necessary to construct a `chararray` (which is an internal implementation detail) manually:

```py
>>> from astropy.io import fits
>>> hdul = fits.open('table.fits')
>>> hdul[1].data
FITS_rec([('d',), ('e',), ('f',)], dtype=(numpy.record, [('a', 'S1')]))
>>> hdul[1].data['a']
chararray(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U1')
>>> hdul[1].data['a'] = ['g', 'e', 'h']
>>> hdul[1].data['a']
chararray(['g', 'e', 'h'], dtype='<U1')
>>> hdul.writeto('table.fits', overwrite=True)
>>> hdul = fits.open('table.fits')
>>> hdul[1].data
FITS_rec([('g',), ('e',), ('h',)], dtype=(numpy.record, [('a', 'S1')]))
```